# How to add a custom extension on navigation?

Tags: api

I create a simple extension but I want to put it on navigation bar.A simple menu inside a events menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for [hook_civicrm_navigationMenu](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/) including the civix helper functions.

Comment: I saw that but didn't understand.

Comment: If you have a sample code then please share on dipakgiree@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an existing navigationMenu hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_navigationMenu().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/
 */
function dmciviapi_civicrm_navigationMenu(&$menu) {

  _dmciviapi_civix_insert_navigation_menu($menu, 'Administer', array(
    'label' => E::ts('Domus Medica API Volledige Rechten'),
    'name' => 'dmciviapi_dmapisettings',
    'url' => 'civicrm/dmciviapi/form/dmapisettings',
    'permission' => 'administer CiviCRM',
    'attributes' => [],
    'operator' => 'OR',
    'separator' => 0,
  ));
  _dmciviapi_civix_navigationMenu($menu);
}
```

In this example the url contains the URL of a form I created with `civix generate:form`